# How do I allow only permitted domains in Tomcat?

Tags: security, tomcat, host, tomcat9

Our PCI compliance vendor is failing our site for "Redirection via Arbitrary Host Header Manipulation."

Both our PCI vendor and a good article on host header attacks recommend "whitelisting permitted domains" as a solution. But I can find no built-in way to do that directly in Tomcat.

I've written the custom Valve below to fill in the gap, and comprehensively accomplish what Tomcat's allowHostHeaderMismatch seems to fail to do.

`<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.HostFilterValve" allow="https\:\/\/.*|http\:\/\/.*\.example.com" />`

```
public class HostFilterValve extends RequestFilterValve
{
    @Override
    public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String property = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName();
        process(property, request, response);
    }
}
```

This tested example lets all https requests through, where the HSTS configuration seems to disallow the vulnerability. It lets http requests from known hosts through, preventing header manipulation while still allowing redirection from "known" hosts to HTTPS. In the future I will likely allow only known domains for both http and https.

Meanwhile, is there a built-in or better way to permit only allowed domains in Tomcat, or otherwise solve the "Redirection via Arbitrary Host Header Manipulation" vulnerability?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69168711/2834978

Comment: Thank you. That was one of the articles we read and tried before posting. Its solution did not work for us; we have appBase specified, and RemoteAddrValve as implemented in the referenced article didn't solve it either, nor does allowHostHeaderMismatch (which is supposed to be default behavior now). However the custom HostFilterValve implemented as described above did pass the vulnerability scan while still allowing http redirection.